# How to inherit height in html with js or jquery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have an `<em`> tag and I have tags inside it. One of the span tags inside this has a height of 45 and this em tag has a height of 41. What I wan't to do is inherit whatever height the tags (the children tags) inside this em have and assign it to this em tag. In this case the em tag should be 45 in height and not 41. Because that's the biggest height value from the tags inside.

What I did was with jquery tried to add overflow inherit and height inherit, but it doesn't work. Any help on how can one achieve such thing would be highly appreciated! Thank you!

```js
    $("em[data-algorithm-type='formula']").css( {'overflow': 'inherit'});
    $("em[data-algorithm-type='formula']").css( {'height': 'inherit'});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title></title>
</head>
<body>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.js"></script>

  <em class="js-match" data-algorithm-type="formula" style="background-color: rgb(0, 231, 255); color: rgb(0, 0, 0); overflow: inherit;">
    <formula>
      <span class="MathJax_Preview" style="color: inherit; display: none;"></span>
      <span id="MathJax-Element-48-Frame" class="mjx-chtml MathJax_CHTML" style="font-size: 118%; position: relative;" role="presentation">d=√(x₁ – x₂)² + (y₁ – y₂)²</span>
  </formula></em>
  
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: As far as I know those are both `inline` tags by default on which you should use `line-height` instead of `height`.

Comment: @Lain thanks for your comment. But also line-height doesn't do the job.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following will fix line-height:

```
$("em[data-algorithm-type='formula']").css( {'display': 'inline-block'});
```

Answer (score 0):

instead of any jquery you can add padding style to `<em>`:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title></title>
</head>
<body>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.js"></script>

  <em class="js-match" data-algorithm-type="formula" style=" padding: 10px; background-color: rgb(0, 231, 255); color: rgb(0, 0, 0); overflow: inherit;">
    <formula>
      <span class="MathJax_Preview" style="color: inherit; display: none;"></span>
      <span id="MathJax-Element-48-Frame" class="mjx-chtml MathJax_CHTML" style="font-size: 118%; position: relative;" role="presentation">d=√(x₁ – x₂)² + (y₁ – y₂)²</span>
  </formula></em>
  
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: thank you for your answer. But no for my case padding is not an option. I already tried that. I need to get the maximum exact height from child tags.